# jQuery - Remove all child elements before specific child

Tags: jquery

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/9krvkfpw/

Hi,

I'm trying to remove all child elements up to a certain point but I'm not too sure what the most effective way to do this is.

Here's some example code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="el1">Remove</div>
    <div id="el2">Remove</div>
    <div id="el3">Remove</div>
    <div id="el4">Remove</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Keep
    </script>
    <div id="lastEl">Keep</div>
</div>
```

Essentially, what I want to do is remove all elements above the script element.  I can't just find the first script element because sometimes there's more above the one I want to keep, so they'll get in the way.

My idea was to get the script tag by hitting the `#lastEl` and getting the previous element.

Like this:

```
var script = $('#container').children('#lastEl').prev();
```

From here I'm not sure what the best way to proceed is, or if this is even the best way?

I could do something like `script.prev().remove()` multiple times, but this isn't always going to work because there's always a different number of elements previous to the script I'm starting with.

Any ideas would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Look into [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).

Comment: try using `$('#container').find('#lastEl').prev().prevAll().remove()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer what you are looking for exactly:

> Essentially, what I want to do is remove all elements above the script element

You can do following:

```
$('#container script').prevAll().remove();
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9krvkfpw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`prevAll` is what you are looking for:

```
$("#lastEl").prevAll("div").remove();
```

Comment: he needs to keep the `script` need another `.prev()` before `.prevAll()`

Comment: No @guradio, that is what `div` does in `prevAll`.

Comment: i missed that one :)

Comment: this is not nice if there is some other type of element, u should list all that case

Comment: Yes, you got a point there. But on the other hand, it could be nice too. When you got other elements there you want to keep, or a second `script` you have to change other approaches too ... @GeorgeGarchagudashvili

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#container').find('#lastEl').prev().prevAll().remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="el1">Remove</div>
    <div id="el2">Remove</div>
    <div id="el3">Remove</div>
    <div id="el4">Remove</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Keep
    </script>
    <div id="lastEl">Keep</div>
</div>
```

Try this approach

Comment: This is correct and works, but why not directly use `$("#lastEl")`?

Comment: @eisbehr i just change a few things on OP original code :)